# how to find out particular URL is correct URL or not in shell script using curl command

Tags: shell

code for fetching date of that url

```
#!/bin/bash
i='http://example.comm'  
response_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is this one:

`curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\n" "https://www.google.com" -o /dev/null -k`

It returns `200` if the page is okay. I tried it on CentOS.

Comment: i am not looking for status, i want to assert something so that i can know, this one is correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the command exit code, not the HTTP status code.

Every time you run a command in Linux, the command's exit code is stored on the *$?* variable. For example:

```
curl  -s globostg.globoi.com >/dev/null 

cmdReturnCode=$?

if [ $cmdReturnCode == "0" ] ; then
    echo SUCCESS
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

The $? variable will reset its value after every command you run.

It also works for function return values:

```
function fail {
    return 1
}
fail
echo $? # prints 1.
```

And remember that in Linux/Unix a return code != 0 means error.